# Why can you not remove downvotes

Tags: discussion, voting

I have on a few occasions in the past, downvoted a question and then after re-evaluation thought that it shouldn’t have been.  When trying to cancel the downvote or changing it to an upvote, I find that I cannot do that unless an edit is made.

Why is that?